# For what integers can this matrix be generated?

Tags: matrices, induction

We call a positive integer $n$ "good" if there exists a $n \times n$ matrix such that:

> 1) Each element is either $0$ or $1$.
>
> 2) Sum of elements in each row is distinct.
>
> 3) Sum of elements in each column is the same of that in all other columns.

For example 2 is good:

$$\begin{matrix}0&0\\1&1\end{matrix}$$

Find the set $\mathbb G$ of good numbers.

I have already tried it on small values of $n$, it seems that such a matrix exists for all $n$ ( that's at least for the values I tried ), is that right? And I'm looking for a concrete proof. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you could prove that there are such matrices for all n by using induction?

Comment: First of all, there exists a `2x2` matrix:
`0 0 _newline_ 1 1`
I thought of using induction, but how can I expand a `nxn` valid matrix to a `(n + 1)x(n + 1)` valid one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $n$ is even, form pairs of rows such that their numbers of $1$s add up to $n$: $(0,n), (1,n-1),\dotsc(n/2-1,n/2+1)$. In each pair, arrange the $1$s such that they don't overlap. Then each pair contributes $1$ to the sum of each column, and the rows sums are all different.

If $n$ is odd, use the pairs $(1,n-1),(2,n-2),\dotsc,((n-1)/2,(n+1)/2)$, and then add a full row of $1$s.

[*Examples for odd $n$ as requested:*]

$n=3$:

$$\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&1\\1&1&1}$$

$n=5$:

$$\pmatrix{1&0&0&0&0\\0&1&1&1&1\\1&1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1&1}$$

Comment: Very elegant solution!

Comment: Nice solution! :D
Thanks a lot.
But, when n is odd, could you clarify more? It would help if you demonstrated when n = 3. Thanks -- again -- in advance! :)

Comment: @Abody97: Sorry, the description of the odd case was wrong; I've fixed it and provided two examples.

Comment: @joriki: Thanks again! But the example for n = 5 doesn't match the description. Well anyway, the idea is clear.

Comment: @Abody97: Why does it not match the description? Because $(2,n-2)$ is the same as $((n-1)/2,(n+1)/2)$ for $n=5$? I think it's usual to write general terms like that; it's implicit that for small values of $n$ the overlapping ones only occur once.

Answer (score 2):

Let's see, each row has sum at most $n.$ 
Thus, the total sum of all entries must be $1+2+3+\dots+n = n(n+1)/2,$
if we do not allow an empty row. However, allowing an empty row
yields that all possible sums for a $n \times n$ matrix is
in the interval $[n(n-1)/2,n(n+1)/2]$. This interval contains $n$ numbers,
so one of them must be divisible by $n,$ say the number $m = cn.$
Thus, each column must have $c$ non-zero entries.

This is easily done, by just rearranging entries in each row, as we may move them between columns without changing rows.